# Python script для Notepad++ убирающий дубликаты строчек

Tags: python, python-3.x, notepad++

может быть у кого-то уже есть готовый скрипт на питоне, который можно использовать как плагин в notepad++ и который убирает все дубликаты строчек, ОСТАВЛЯЯ самое верхнее значение

**я знаю что можно регулярками это сделать, но в том случае остаётся нижнее значение, и бывали случаи, когда не всё шло корректно...

поэтому хотелось бы сделать через Скрипт на питоне...

а также, забыл написать, что важно чтобы порядок строк никак не менялся!!
строчек много, допустим 5000
дубликаты разбросаны, и могут быть где угодно
нужно убрать все точные совпадения строк

искал на форумах и пробовал... но верного результата так и не удалось добиться...

До Скрипта:
Sndwave - Without You
Ben Delay - Believe'20
Jack Back - Freedom
Simioli - Tears Dry On Their Own
Milk Bar - Feel So High
Redfield - Never The Same
Scotty Boy - Keep On Rocking
Jack Back - Freedom
Simioli - Tears Dry On Their Own
Milk Bar - Feel So High

После Скрипта:
Sndwave - Without You
Ben Delay - Believe'20
Jack Back - Freedom
Simioli - Tears Dry On Their Own
Milk Bar - Feel So High
Redfield - Never The Same
Scotty Boy - Keep On Rocking

прошу помочь...

Comment: смотря как написать регулярку

Comment: а чем отличается самое верхнее значение от самого нижнего если речь идет о дубликатах? ;) Или надо учитывать не только дубликаты __идущих подряд__ строк?

Comment: я имел ввиду что из дублирующихся строк, остаётся верхняя, а не нижняя

Comment: а также, забыл написать, что важно чтобы порядок строк никак не менялся!!

Comment: дубликаты могут быть разбросаны по всему TXT, строчек может быть очень много, например 5000

Comment: Приведите примеры входных и выходных данных для наглядности.

Comment: Easy. Используйте `set()` и построчное чтение. Что-то типа: `dups = set() for line in open(filename, 'rt').readlines(): if line in dups: continue dups.add(line) print(line)` (за точность не ручаюсь, но идею вы поняли) Можно дальше там оптимизировать с помощью `splitlines()`, `with` и прочих новомодных штучек.

Comment: добавил пример в тело вопроса!  
  
по поводу команд, я в них ничего не понимаю... там одна неверная скобка всё перестаёт работать... поэтому и прошу помочь.. нужен готовый скрипт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну если вам лень копировать из коментария, то вот:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python -tt
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
# vim: ts=4 sw=4 et ai si

from __future__ import print_function

import sys

def main(argv):
    if len(argv) < 2:
        raise SystemExit("No given file")

    dups = set()
    for line in open(argv[1], 'rt').readlines():
        if line in dups:
            continue
        dups.add(line)
        sys.stdout.write(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Сохраняете в файл, например, *remove_duplicate_lines.py* и запускаете так

```sh
$ ./remove_duplicate_lines.py my_cool_file_with_dups.txt
Sndwave - Without You
Ben Delay - Believe'20
Jack Back - Freedom
Simioli - Tears Dry On Their Own
Milk Bar - Feel So High
Redfield - Never The Same
Scotty Boy - Keep On Rocking
```

Чтобы запустить в Notepad++ как вставку, надо вначале установить [PythonScript](https://github.com/bruderstein/PythonScript/) (GitHub) и [PythonScript](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above) (простая установка). Скрипт, конечно, тоже придётся поменять (не тестировался за неимением Notepad++).

```py
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
# vim: ts=4 sw=4 et ai si

from Npp import editor, notepad

duplicates = None

def remove(contents, lineNumber, totalLines):
    global duplicates
    if contents in duplicates:
        editor.deleteLine(lineNumber)
        return 0 # same line
    duplicates.add(contents)
    return 1 # next line

def main():
    global duplicates
    duplicates = set()
    editor.forEachLine(remove)
    notepad.messageBox("Removals completed", "Duplicate removal (based on Python Script)", 0)

main()
```

Использовался как основа [Remove and Modify selected lines](https://github.com/bruderstein/PythonScript/blob/master/scripts/Samples/Remove%20and%20Modify%20selected%20lines.py).